# Why new pulled code from git not applied when Gunicorn running on ubuntu server?

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I have a **django** project on ubuntu server that works with **Nginx** and **Gunicorn** correctrly.
I change some django code and push on git server and then pull from git server on ubuntu server. It seems new changes not implemented on server. How to fix it?
I restart and reload Gunicorn and Nginx but not happend.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Git. It's just a general thing that applies to all systemd users. (So it's not really django, nginx, or gunicorn either, and it's a superuser.com type question about using systemd, rather than a programming question.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer we can enter command like this for restarting Gunicorn:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```